# embedded google sheet not editable on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, iframe, google-sheets, edit

I have a google sheet which I want to be editable from my web app (embedded using an iframe) and I have set the correct permissions.

The code is like this

```
<iframe width="1300" height="800" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10V-_rutEKaQ19yVmMFz2Fs4f4rdibfKIivLIwTBVp6g/edit?usp=sharing"></iframe>
```

While everything is OK on my PC and Linux laptop, for some reason editing is not possible on mobile devices (both Android and iOS).

The only way I can edit the sheet on mobile devices is by opening it directly with the google sheets app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone can shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

It works only if I specifically in mobile Chrome request desktop version of the site with embedded document. After that desktop version of site is reloaded and I am able to edit document inside browser.
I tried to find a way to specify in worpdress explicitly to always load "desktop version only" on mobile, but without luck.